# Sqlite command to list supported extensions

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Would you remind me a Sqlite command (like SQL) which lists all supported extensions like ICU, Fts, Vfs so on.

I know this command exists and I saw it in one StackOverflow post but, to my shame, I can't find it neither here nor in documentation.

Comment: Please search better

Comment: Thanks :). I did found the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881370/way-to-find-out-which-compilation-options-were-used-to-build-sqlite.