# Enabling usleep() support in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I make Flask-SQLAlchemy use a self-compiled sqlite with support for usleep()?

I am using `Flask 0.10.1` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1` with `Python 3.4.0` to provide a microservice running in `Ubuntu 14.04`. As database backend for my app, I'm using SQLite with default settings:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/my-database.db'
```

The installed version of SQLite3 is 3.8.2.

In the course of operating my service, I occasionally see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

The microservice does not hold any database connections for a prolonged period of time, so at first this issue looked inexplicable to me. I did some research and came across the article [the SQLite lock timeout nightmare](http://beets.radbox.org/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html). It suggests that SQLite can be compiled without `usleep()` support and therefore may only try to lock the database in full-second intervals. Given that the default lock timeout for SQLite is 5 seconds we basically have 5 attempts to try a database connection before it fails. [Inspection of my SQLite compile flags](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options) also reveals that HAVE_USLEEP was not set. Also, SQLAlchemy does not allow setting a different pool timeout for SQLite, since a `NullPool` is used. **I want to substitute SQLite by a version which supports usleep() to reduce the probability of lock timeouts. How can it be done?**

Comment: How do you inspect your SQLite compile flags? How would one use the `PRAGMA compile_options;` in python to do that?

Comment: I figured it out! The python for that is `cur.execute('PRAGMA compile_options')`. [Here's an example](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) of using a pragam (scroll to the Metadata section). Unfortunately, it looks like one [won't necessarily get all compile time options using this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881370/way-to-find-out-which-compilation-options-were-used-to-build-sqlite)